# How to effecentily rename a file in linux CLI by inserting new characters into the existing name?

Tags: linux, command-line, file-management

Let's say I have a long file name such as `longfilename`. And for the sake of brevity, let's say that "longfilename" is actually much more longer, and more complex to type. Anyway, I want to rename it to `long12345filename` from the command line. Currently I am aware of running the command

```
mv longfilename long12345filename
```

However, in this example, the best I can do is type `mv long[tab] long12345filename` ... Basically lots of manual typing. Isn't there a way to edit a filename by brining up the current filename and moving the cursor to where you want new characters inserted/deleted ?

Comment: Why is `mv long[tab] long[tab]` and moving the cursor not an option?

Comment: Because it's long, duh. :D Please tell us more about your desired filename pattern.

Comment: When you have many similarly named files, it frequently takes many tabs and character entries to reach enough uniqueness to complete the desired file, it's annoying to do that twice if you don't have to.

Comment: If you have a nice terminal window, then just double click on the original filename (assuming it has no spaces in the name) and then mid-click-space-mid-click to copy and paste it a couple times.  Then position  your cursor and make your edits.

Comment: @gronostaj Let's say the file name is longer, and composed of many serial ID's, like this for example: `T.359230514.EFT.ON.MYFILE.D20140829.T1845329`  And let's say I wanted to insert characters after "MYFILE". And let's say that tab would bring up way too many results. Basically, longfilename is just a place holder for any file where tabbing would have too many results and be too difficult to type out.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bash, and you have a rule for the transformation of the filename
that you can articulate clearly (e.g., insert `12345` after the first `g`), you can do

```
mv longTab !#:$:s/g/g12345/
```

Words beginning with `!` are history references. 
`!#` refers to the current command (so far). 
`:$` means the last word on the line, so, after `mv longfilename`, `!#:$` refers to `longfilename`. 
And finally `:s/old/replacement/` is simple search and replace.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the use of a file manager for the command line, like:

[Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/)

[Last File Manager](http://www.terra.es/personal7/inigoserna/lfm/)

[Vifm](http://vifm.sourceforge.net/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I do this in an iterative fashion which works but I'm sure there is a better way.

`mv long[tab][enter]` (displays error, missing operand)

`[up arrow][cntrl+e][space]!$` (displays error, same file)

`[up arrow]` now you have mv longfilename longfilename on the command line and you can move the cursor where you want and edit in place.